# I want to display the profile image after login

Tags: php, html, mysql, session

Login Html

```
<form class="user" action="code.php" method="POST">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control form-control-user"  placeholder="Enter Email Address...">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control form-control-user" placeholder="Password">
                </div>

                <button type="submit" name="login_btn" class="btn btn-primary btn-user btn-block">
                  Login
                </button>
                <hr>



              <div class="text-center">
                <a class="small" href="forgot-password.html">Forgot Password?</a>
              </div>
             </form>
```

Header in index.php

```
  <span class="mr-2 d-none d-lg-inline text-gray-600 small">

              <?php
             echo $_SESSION['username'];
              ?>

            </span>
            <img class="img-profile rounded-circle" src="<?php echo $_SESSION['image']; ?>"
```

**This is the header in index.php :**

> [image: IMAGE1]

**This is the image field in the user table in the database :**

[image: IMAGE2]

I want to display the profile image after login the image is in the image table in my database.

I'm a newbie in PHP

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing an access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Any modern [development framework](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/best-php-frameworks/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with an [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in, and there are [authentication libraries](http://phprbac.net/) you can use. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text** or a weak hash like **SHA1 or MD5**.

Comment: Does your HTML contain the correct `src=` attribute? It's worth inspecting the source to find out.

Comment: Is your image tag closed?

Comment: Are the images stored in the same directory as `index.php`? If not, you need to put the appropriate directory in `$_SESSION['image']`

Comment: You can use browser inspect element and console log to see the error. Error you get is because of the src is looking for the file. mean its looking something like "http://myurl//images/1x1.png"

Answer (score 1):

you can make a directory and upload the images with a name of unique id of username and after login show the image like this

```
<img class="img-profile rounded-circle"  src="/userimg/<?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>"/>
```

home this will help